# Angular Form Keep Disabled after Reset

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular11

I have a dropdown set as Disabled. However, everytime I reset the form, `customerForm.reset()`  , the dropdown becomes enabled, and not disabled.

Its hardcoded to disabled below = true .

How can I keep it as disabled after each reset?

```
<form [formGroup]="customerForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Product List</mat-label>
        <mat-select
          formControlName="product"
          [disabled]="true">
             <mat-option>Select</mat-option>
             <mat-option
             *ngFor="let productItem of productList"
             [value]="productItem "
             >
             {{ productItem }}
             </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Note: would like to keep value in the form, without using getRawValue if possible.

Comment: try changing `formControlName="{{ product }}"` to `formControlName="product"`. It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive

Comment: hi @StacksQueue I just changed it, just a typo

Comment: Is it always disabled? when will the user can select the `productItem`?

Comment: @StacksQueue  its disabled at the beginning, then I press a button to clear/reset the form, and that is when the dropdown becomes enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `clear/reset` function, you can add this:

```
this.customerForm.controls['product'].disabled();
```

Or

you can initialize in your `formGroup`

```
customerForm = this.fb.group({
   product: [{value: '', disabled: true}]
});
```

And omit the `[disabled]="true"` in your `mat-select`

Comment: well if its disabled in Reactive forms, I have to do this getRawValue, which I prefer not at this point, wondering why reset is removing my html disabled

Comment: do you have to get it's value before resetting?